# NetBeans - TaskFactory (Parsing API) does not work if a ProjectFactory (Project API) was registered

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-7.3

I'm creating a NetBeans module with multiple services (code assist, project, debugger etc.)

I've noticed that after I registered my ProjectFactory via the `@ServiceProvider` annotation, the TaskFactory which is registered by the `@MimeRegistration` annotation stops working. I.e. its one and only method `create(Snapshot snapshot)` for creating parsing tasks, like ParserResultTasks for error annotations, is not being invoked anymore, thus no parsing.

However, once I invoke the parser explicitly, e.g. through `ParserManager.parse` within a CompletionProvider, everything works again. Also, I should probably note that the project, editor and parser implementations are all in separate modules.

Is there anything else I have to pay attention to if the ProjectFactory and TaskFactory are being used together? Perhaps adding the TaskFactory to the lookup of the project?

**Update**

All of a sudden everything is working. I don't know what the problem was, perhaps the META registrations haven't been loaded correctly after changes were made? I don't know. But now everything seems to do what it supposed do.

I'm still open for possible suggestions where things can go wrong when using both, project and parsing API together (if that at all was the problem).

**Update2**

No, it's not working.
Filed in a bug report, see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230558

Comment: Yeah, it sounds as if a Clean/Build All took care of creating the layer file entries in one of your modules. I would recommend asking for "possible suggestions where things can go wrong..." on the NetBeans Platform Users forum. http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html

Comment: @JonathanSpooner I wish it was that, unfortunately it wasn't. See my Update2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out it was a bug after all, but it has been fixed now.

See the full story over [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230558).